# pthread_create() fails with EAGAIN at 291 cycle

Tags: c, pthreads

I had this code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  pthread_t thread[thr_num];
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

  // just for debugging //
    struct rlimit rlim;
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, &rlim);
    printf ("soft = %d \n", rlim.rlim_cur);
    printf ("hard = %d \n", rlim.rlim_max);
  ////

  for ( i = 1 ; i <= thr_num ; i++) {
    if(pthread_create( &thread[i], &attr, loggerThread, (void*)argv ) ) {
      printf("pthread_create failure, i = %d, errno = %d \n", i, errno);
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

  for ( i = 1 ; i <= thr_num ; i++) {
    if( pthread_join(thread[i], (void**)&status ) ) {
      exit(1);
    }
  }  

  return 0;
}

void* loggerThread(void* data) 
{
  char** sthg = ((char**)data);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I don't understand why when I run this code with thr_num=291, I got an error:
    pthread_create failure, i = 291, errno = 11   (EAGAIN)

with thr_num=290 worked fine. I run this code on a Linux 2.6.27.54-0.2-default (SLES 11)
The rlim.rlim_cur has value 6906 the rlim.rlim_max also. The same I saw with 'ulimit -a' for 'max user processes'.
I checked also /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max  (it was 13813) guided by pthread_create man page.
Did not find any parameters with value 290 for 'sysctl -a' output either.

Ocassionally I found out from this link:
[pthread_create and EAGAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634736/pthread-create-and-eagain)
that: "Even if pthread_exit or pthread_cancel is called, the parent process still need to call pthread_join to release the pthread ID, which will then become recyclable"

so just as a try I modified my code to this:

```
for ( i = 1 ; i <= thr_num ; i++) {
  if(pthread_create( &thread[i], &attr, loggerThread, (void*)argv ) ) {
    printf("pthread_create failure, i = %d, errno = %d \n", i, errno);
    exit(1);
  }

  if( pthread_join(thread[i], (void**)&status ) ) {
    printf("pthread_join failure, i = %d, errno = %d \n", i, errno);
    exit(1);
  }     
}
pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
```

and then everything worked: I didn't get the error at 291 cycle.

I would like to understand why with my original code I got the error:
1. because of a wrong programing with threads
2. or I hit some system limit what I couldn't identify

Also would like to know if my correction is good for this problem or what hidden things, pitfalls I eventually introduced with this solution ?
Thanks !

Comment: Don't know what the original problem is, and I'm also curious about it, but the solution you used renders threads usage useless.

The point in using threads is that you can execute tasks in parallel in order to maximize performance, and what you are doing there is creating a thread, than waiting for it to finish before creating other (more on pthread_join: linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join); the functionally ends up being the same as calling a function, with no added benefits. (please someone correct me if I said something wrong)

Comment: You're writing out of bounds in your array:
for ( i = 1 ; i <= thr_num ; i++)  --> for ( i = 0 ; i < thr_num ; i++)

Comment: 200+ threads? You got to be kidding me. Call the doctor!

Comment: While I agree that 200 threads is overkill, this could be an academic exercise. On the other hand, could be some code running on a Parallella, 36 core IBM system z, or a 16-core SPARC capable of dealing with 512 threads.

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to understand why with my original code I got the error: 1. because of a wrong 
>   programing with threads 2. or I hit some system limit what I couldn't identify

You likely hit a system limit. Likely you ran out of address space. Default, each thread gets 8-10Mb of stack space on linux. If you create 290 threads, that's using nearly 3Gb of address space - the max for a 32 bit process.

You get EAGAIN in such a case, since there arn't enough resources to create the thread just now (since there isn't enough address space available at the time).

When a thread exits, not all resources of the thread is released (on linux, the entire stack of the thread is kept around).

- If the thread is in a detached state, e.g. you called pthread_detach() or specified a detached state when it was created as an attribute to  pthread_create(), all resources are release when the thread exits - but you can't pthread_join() a detached thread.
- If the thread is not detached, you need to call  pthread_join() on it to release the resources.

Note that the modified code of yours where you call pthread_join() inside the loop will:

1. spawn a thread
2. Wait for that thread to finish
3. go to 1

i.e. only one other thread is running at a time - which seems a bit pointless.

You can certainly spawn more than one thread that run concurrently - but there's a limit. On your machine, you seem to have found the limit to be around 290.

Comment: An out of memory would be an errno 12. As I mentioned in a comment above, the code is wrong. In each of the for() loops OP is writing out of bounds. I've compiled and run the code on a machine here and have no problems with even 32000 +/- 1 threads.

Comment: @PurpleAlien You're on a 64 bit machine then. although this seems to depend on the glibc version you may get EAGAIN in the situation described here, not ENOMEM. And remember that other operating systems may behave slightly different.

Comment: Yes I'm on a 64 bit machine. The OP has thus two problems if he's really running on a 32 bit machine - which was not clarified.

Answer (score 2):

I initially wrote this as a comment, but just in case...

Your code:

```
  for ( i = 1 ; i <= thr_num ; i++) {
    if(pthread_create( &thread[i], &attr, loggerThread, (void*)argv ) ) {
      printf("pthread_create failure, i = %d, errno = %d \n", i, errno);
      exit(1);
    }
  }
...
  for ( i = 1 ; i <= thr_num ; i++) {
    if( pthread_join(thread[i], (void**)&status ) ) {
      exit(1);
    }
  }
```

In both the for() loops you check from 1 - thr_num. This means you are out of bounds in your array thread[thr_num] since arrays start at index 0. You should thus iterate from 0 to one less than thr_num:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < thr_num ; i++)
```

I'm actually surprised you didn't get a segmentation fault before hitting 291 as thr_num.

Comment: The array is allocated on the stack, so I think the address pointed by thread+thr_num does not exceed the stack space, thus avoiding the fault

Comment: @Rerito, just ran some test here and I get segfaults when thr_num is odd. With even thr_num, no segfault occurs.