# pthread_create fails with EAGAIN

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Consider this code snippet here, where I am trying to create a bunch of threads which end up processing a given task which simulates a race-condition.

```
const int thread_count = 128;
pthread_t threads[thread_count];

for (int n = 0; n != thread_count; ++n)
{
    ret = pthread_create(&threads[n], 0, test_thread_fun, &test_thread_args);
    if( ret != 0 )
    {
        fprintf( stdout, "Fail %d %d", ret, errno );
        exit(0);
     }
 }
```

Things generally works fine except occasionally pthread_create fails with errno EAGAIN "resource temporarily unavailable", I tried inducing usleep, and retry creating but with no real effect.

the failure is sporadic and on some boxes no failures and on some occurs very frequently.

any Idea what could be going wrong here ?

> Edit - 1

update on max-threads

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
256467
```

> Edit 2

I think the inputs here kept me thinking, i'll probably do the below and post any results that are worth sharing.

1. set stack size to a minimum value, I don't think thread_function uses any large arrays.
2. increase my memory and swap ( and nullify any side effects )
3. write a script to monitor the system behavior and see any other process/system daemon is interfering when this case is run, which is in turn can cause resource crunch.
4. system hard and soft limits are pretty high so I'll leave them as they are at this point.

Comment: Man page says "EAGAIN The system lacked the necessary resources to create another thread, or the system-imposed limit on the total number of threads in a  process {PTHREAD_THREADS_MAX} would be exceeded."

Comment: 128 is kind a lot of threads.

Comment: I guess so but then the this is quite a high end box

Comment: @Karthick in which case the failure should have been consistent

Comment: Available system resources vary from time to time depending on what else is running on the system. So there's no necessity for the failure to be "consistent".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634736/pthread-create-and-eagain

Comment: That code above has an extended code ( not present in question ) where main threads on pthread_join to check nothing is cancelled and few other validations on join, so detach is not quite the option I’m looking for.

Comment: The default stack size for new threads is usually quite large, something like 8 megabytes. The amount of memory required by the thread stacks is typically the first limiting factor. You can use `pthread_attr_init()` and `pthread_attr_setstacksize()` to create a pthread attribute that describes the stack size for new threads (you can reuse the one for all threads). On most architectures, if the thread worker function does not have large local arrays or deep nesting, 65536 bytes tends to work fine. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12397558/1475978) for an example.

Comment: `errno` is not relevant here, as [`pthread_create` returns its own error code](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html#tag_16_424_04).  What is the value of `ret` when you experience this failure?

Comment: it returns 11 every time it fails

Comment: Another reason explained [here](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/problem_of_thread_creation.html): process's virtual memory space is fragmented.

Answer (score 1):

If your program makes sure that it never creates more threads than the system limit allows for (by joining threads before creating new ones), then you are likely running into this kernel bug:

- [Task exit is signaled before task resource allocation, leading to bogus EAGAIN errors](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154011)

With certain kinds of container technology, the race window appears to be much larger, and the bug is much easier to trigger.  (This might depend on the types of cgroups in use.)

Answer (score 1):

There are not enough resources to start a new thread.
Check if you have zombie threads on your system, or that you have enough memory etc on the system.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a system limit about the max number of thread per process. Try to see it with:
`cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`

Answer (score 0):

Check `ulimit -a` at your shell. You likely have a process limit set in login policy and Linux ridiculously also applies this to threads.