# Error with new thread creation when thread pool reused

Tags: java, aws-lambda, java-11

Consider a code (run in aws lambda):

```
    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(threadCount);
    var deleteFiles = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->
            files.parallelStream().forEach(file -> /*come blocking code here*/),
        forkJoinPool
    );
    deleteFiles.get();
    var copiedFiles = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->
            syncFiles.parallel().forEach(file -> /*come blocking code here*/)
        ),
        forkJoinPool
    );
    copiedFiles.get();
```

`threadCount` value is `900`

A code before `deleteFiles.get()` works fine but during "second" part I got:

```
10.934s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
```

It looks like on second parallel stream `ForkJoinPool` creates new threads and keep old same time. Is it? How to keep thread count
be less or equal to `threadCount`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078106/pthread-create-fails-with-eagain

Comment: It depends on what kind of blocking operation you are using. For some operations (those using [`ManagedBlocker`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker.html) under the hood), the `ForkJoinPool` might create compensation threads. Mind that the number passed to `ForkJoinPool`’s constructor is not a thread count but a target parallelism. For example, calling `join()` on a `CompletableFuture` is such an operation.