# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached" if program started by cron

Tags: java, cron, out-of-memory

I have a java program that runs totally fine on my UNIX webserver when I start it through a normal shell command (java -jar xxx.jar)

However, I am trying a scheduled run through cron and receive the following error:

```
[0.075s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:801)
```

As said, it does not seem to be a java coding error since it seems to be running without any problems when started to shell. Nor it seems to be an error with cron since  other java programs are being executed fine.

I read that the system resources for cron are limited. So I checked the user limits in the system:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1545091
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 62987
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

And then I adjusted the systemd for cron:

```
$ systemctl stop cron
$ sudo systemctl edit cron
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl start cron
```

And, in the file for "systemctl edit cron" I tried to replicate the ulimit values
(mapping found at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345595/how-to-set-ulimits-on-service-with-systemd)

```
TasksMax=unlimited
LimitCORE=unlimited
LimitDATA=unlimited
LimitFSIZE=unlimited
LimitSIGPENDING=1545091
LimitMEMLOCK=65536
LimitRSS=unlimited
LimitNOFILE=1024
LimitSTACK=unlimited
LimitCPU=unlimited
LimitNPROC=62987
LimitAS=unlimited
LimitLOCKS=unlimited
```

However, this all didn't help much, the error when cron tries to start the program is still the same.

Since I am totally out of my wits here, any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: What happens when you run the program without cron?

Comment: **possibly** out of memory, which means, Java has no idea.
Did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078106/pthread-create-fails-with-eagain bring you in correct direction?

Comment: @Julia, As said, without cron the program runs just fine

Comment: Add a cron entry to capture output from ulimit: `* * * * * ulimit -a > /path/to/ulimit-cron-output.txt` - only need to leave it just for a minute to capture the output, then remove the crontab entry. This would let you see if the reported ulimit data (when running via cron) is consistent with the changes you tried to make.

Answer (score 3):

So, after some further research I found out that the "DefaultMaxTasks" had to be changed for the overall system as well as for the cron service. The value was set to 195 which was too low.

Helpful links were:
https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000015901
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/configuring-defaulttasksmax-for-suse.html#GUID-0815D18D-65E7-46B2-BA89-F54BA02EFCB8

change the overall DefaultTasksMax:

```
$ systemctl show --property DefaultTasksMax
DefaultTasksMax=195
$ cd /etc/systemd
$ vi system.conf
(set DefaultTasksMax = 65535)
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl show --property DefaultTasksMax
DefaultTasksMax=65535
```

change values for cron:

```
$ cd cron.service.d
$ ls
override.conf
$ vi override.conf
```

in the override.conf, I set the new values incl. DefaultTasksMax:

```
DefaultTasksMax=65535
LimitCORE=unlimited
LimitDATA=unlimited
LimitFSIZE=unlimited
LimitSIGPENDING=1545091
LimitMEMLOCK=65536
LimitRSS=unlimited
LimitNOFILE=1024
LimitSTACK=unlimited
LimitCPU=unlimited
LimitNPROC=62987
LimitAS=unlimited
LimitLOCKS=unlimited
```

and the check shows set the value is also newly set for cron:

```
$ systemctl status cron.service |grep -e Tasks
Tasks: 5 (limit: 65535)
```

After that, the problem was resolved

Comment: how do it in windows?